# Bind Two gridview to the same binding source at the same form

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

Hi There I Have Master Details and two gridview
I need to bind them to the same binding source at the same form
and make the id(auto number) at gridview1 take the value -1 and in gridview2 = -2

Right Now the id at gridview = -1 and at gridview2 = -1 
and that is wrong for me :( 
How Can I Do That ??? .net

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create two binding sources that are bound to the same data and apply them individually - by binding them to the same source your effectively tying them together - you can see this in action if you bind two dropdown/comboboxes to the same source, when you change one the other will change with it.

```
Dim ds as ---Your Data Source---

Dim bs1 as new BindingSource
bs1.DataSource = ds

Dim bs2 as new BindingSource
bs2.DataSource = ds

GridView1.DataSource = bs1
GridView2.DataSource = bs2
```